# SQL - Grab Rows That Are Between 2 Dates Using Different Tables

Tags: sql, t-sql, datetime

I have 2 tables:

**Table 1:**

```
Name, StartDate, EndDate
```

Ex:

```
Timmy, 9/12/17 08:00:00, 9/13/17 00:00:00   
Timmy, 9/13/17 05:00:00, 9/13/17 07:00:00
```

Table 2:

```
Name, StartHour, Data...
```

Ex:

```
Timmy, 9/13/17 06:00:00, Data1...   
Timmy, 9/13/17 04:00:00, Data2...   
Timmy, 9/13/17 07:00:00, Data3...  
Timmy, 9/12/17 14:00:00, Data4...
```

So, I need to get every record in Table 2 where that start hour is NOT inside of a date range in Table 1. This needs to be done for every name (so there can be multiple matching names in T1/T2 (see T2's data columns are different). It should be inclusive on the left side, exclusive on the right side.

So for this query, I want to see

```
Timmy, 9/13/17 04:00:00, Data2...  
Timmy, 9/13/17 07:00:00, Data3... (Inclusive on end date)
```

I don't mind if its joined; I can just remove extra columns. I don't want to see duplicates though. I also keep hitting problems where I'll check if NOT (StartHour  >= StartDate AND StartHour < EndDate). So each row/startHour in Table 2 needs to be checked against every row with a matching name in Table 1. I can't deal with that; I think it needs a subquery, but I don't know.

Checking if it is inside the ranges, but then negate because I don't want them if they are inside the range (inclusive,exclusive).

Comment: `... where not exists ( select 42 from ... )` may help.

Comment: What does your query currently look like? Are you getting any errors or incorrect results?

Answer (score 1):

Given the following tables:

```
CREATE TABLE #table1 ([Name] VARCHAR(15), startdate DATETIME, enddate DATETIME)
CREATE TABLE #table2 ([Name] VARCHAR(15), starthour DATETIME, [data] VARCHAR(MAX))

INSERT INTO #table1 (Name, startdate, enddate)
VALUES ('Timmy','9/12/17 08:00:00','9/13/17 00:00:00'),
('Timmy','9/13/17 05:00:00','9/13/17 07:00:00')

INSERT INTO #table2 (Name, starthour, data)
VALUES ('Timmy','9/13/17 06:00:00','Data1...'),
('Timmy','9/13/17 04:00:00','Data2...'),
('Timmy','9/13/17 07:00:00','Data3...'),
('Timmy','9/12/17 14:00:00','Data4...')
```

The following query seems to work for what you want:

```
SELECT t2.name, t2.starthour, t2.[data] 
FROM #table2 t2
INNER JOIN #table1 t1 ON t1.name = t2.name
WHERE t2.starthour BETWEEN t1.startdate AND t1.enddate
```

Results:

```
[name]  [starthour]             [Data]
----------------------------------------
Timmy   2017-09-13 06:00:00.000 Data1...
Timmy   2017-09-13 07:00:00.000 Data3...
Timmy   2017-09-12 14:00:00.000 Data4...
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested above, `NOT EXISTS` is probably the way to go here. `NOT IN` is another option. The idea being that you base the query on Table 2, then filter the output in the WHERE clause using NOT EXISTS against Table 1.

For example:

```
SELECT
    t2.Name,
    t2.StartHour
FROM #Table2 t2
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM #Table1 t1
        WHERE t1.Name = t2.Name
            AND t1.StartDate <= t2.StartHour
            AND t2.EndDate > t2.StartHour
    );
```

More information on EXISTS here, as well as a comparison between EXISTS and IN:

[EXISTS (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/exists-transact-sql)